# How to handle utf-8 text with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to parse various text sources and then print / store it somewhere.

Every time a non ASCII character is encountered, I can't correctly print it as it gets converted to bytes, and I have no idea how to view the correct characters.

(I'm quite new to Python, I come from PHP where I never had any utf-8 issues)

The following is a code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import feedparser

url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/japanese/rss.xml"
feeds = feedparser.parse(url)
title = feeds['feed'].get('title').encode('utf-8')

print(title)

file = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(str(title))
file.close()
```

I'd like to print and write in a file the RSS title (BBC Japanese - ホーム) but instead the result is this:

> b'BBC Japanese - \xe3\x83\x9b\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x83\xa0'

Both on screen and file. Is there a proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python3 `bytes` and `str` are two different types - and `str` is used to represent any type of string (also unicode), when you `encode()` something, you convert it from it's `str` representation to it's `bytes` representation for a specific encoding.

In your case in order to the decoded strings, you just need to remove the `encode('utf-8')` part:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import feedparser

url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/japanese/rss.xml"
feeds = feedparser.parse(url)
title = feeds['feed'].get('title')

print(title)

file = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(title)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Dean, but in this case the print has this exception, that I encountered before, but could not fix: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 15-17: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Which version of python are you using exactly? This works for me on the latest version of python...

Comment: Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) on Windows

Comment: The default consoles on windows aren't very friendly to the printing of unicode chars. Is the text written to the file properly?

Comment: You are right, the file is correctly written. Seem easier than expected! Now I have to fix the Windows console issue.

Answer (score 2):

JSON data to Unicode support for Japanese characters

```py
def jsonFileCreation (messageData, fileName): 
   with open(fileName, "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
         json.dump(messageData, outfile, indent=8, sort_keys=False,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Please paste code snippet inside ``` and close it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `print(A)` in python3 will first convert the string `A` to bytes with its original encoding, and then print it through 'gbk' encoding.
So if you want to print `A` in utf-8, you first need to convert `A` with gbk as follow:

```
print(A.encode('gbk','ignore').decode('gbk'))
```

Comment: Isn't UTF-8 the default in Python3?

Comment: “utf-8 default in python3” means what you are editing is in utf-8，but in windows, the "print" method can only print string which can be encoded in gbk. The reason is what I have answered.